# How i correct my jazzcash account expiry date error

Tags: android, date, account

I put the wrong expiry date on my jazzcash increase account verification they respond me to fix the right date of you cnic put it but it show me the error so please guide me & help me to fix & put the right date of expiry can get it to my account verification process

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.